# Open web.config from console application?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a console capplication that runs on the same computer that hosts a bunch of web.config files.  I need the console application to open each web.config file and decrypt the connection string and then test if the connection string works.

The problem I am running into is that OpenExeConfiguration is expecting a winforms application configuration file (app.dll.config) and OpenWebConfiguration needs to be run through IIS.  Since this is my local machine, I'm not running IIS (I use Visual Studio's built-in server).

Is there a way I can open the web.config files while still getting the robustness of .NET's capabilities to decrypt the connectionstrings?

Thanks

**Update**
The OpenWebConfiguration works if you are querying IIS directly or are the website in question that you want to look up the web.config for.  What I am looking to accomplish is the same sort of functionality, but from a console application opening up the web.config file of a website on my same machine not using an IIS query because IIS isn't running on my machine.

Comment: Just a sidenote, if your connection strings leverage trusted connections through use of an application pool identity this method likely will not work. If you aren't using trusted connections, shame on you! :)

Comment: @Abyss If trusted connections are being used, there is no point encrypting them. It's not always possible to use Trusted (ie cross domain, politics, external host)

Comment: Hi all,

No trusted connections.  Cross domain situation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok I got it... compiled and accessed this so i know it works...

```
      VirtualDirectoryMapping vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(@"C:\test", true);
            WebConfigurationFileMap wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
            wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);


            // Get the Web application configuration object.
            Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");

            ProtectSection(config, @"connectionStrings", "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
```

This is assuming you have a file called web.config in a directory called C:\Test.

I adjusted @Dillie-O's methods to take a Configuration as a parameter.

You must also reference System.Web and System.configuration and any dlls containing configuration handlers that are set up in your web.config.

Comment: I only mention this because you are new (by the points you have) you can also upvote my answer in addition to marking it the right one.

Answer (score 3):

The when the ConfigurationManager class grab a section from the config file, it has an "IsProtected" property that it can infer for a given section that you grab. If it is protected, you can then Unprotect it using some code.

The basic method for encrypting/decrypting goes like this (taken from article link below):

```
private void ProtectSection(string sectionName, string provider)
{
    Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section =
                 config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null &&
              !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        config.Save();
    }
}

private void UnProtectSection(string sectionName)
{
    Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section =
              config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null &&
          section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

Check out [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043331/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx) for the full details on working with this.

Comment: Hi,
I understand how to test for protected sections, the problem is that I'm trying to open a web.config file from a console application.  The example you provided shows a web application opening its own web.config file.

Comment: +1 late in arrival, since i used the methods you submitted in your answer seems like i should give you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static string WebKey(string key)
    {

        var configFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(webconfigPath);
        var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName, true, configFile.Name);
        var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
        wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
        System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
        System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement kv = appSettingSection.Settings.AllKeys
                         .Where(x => x.Equals(key))
                         .Select(x => appSettingSection.Settings[key])
                         .FirstOrDefault();

        return kv != null ? kv.Value : string.Empty;

    }
```

Comment: Can you add some descriptions for your codes, it will help us to understand your solution well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use WebConfigurationManager class with its [OpenWebConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx) method.

It takes a path to the web.config and should open it just like it would in a HTTPContext based application.