# OpenExeConfiguration Path Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, web-config

I'm trying to load an web.config from a server.
Its placed at: \server\folders\web.config

when i try this:

```
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"\\server\folders\web.config");
```

it searches for: web.config.config and fails.

```
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"\\server\folders\web");
```

it fails, because there is no folder \server\folders\web\

So i tried several things and it seems as its checking wether the file the path is pointing on exists, and afterwards it appliers a .config and gets the config file.

Just for fun i created an web.loaders file, and a web.loaders.config file. with

```
 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"\\server\folders\web.local");
```

it loads the \server\folders\web.local.config perfectly, but throws Exceptions without the web.local file.

So there a many ways to get this small thing loaded, but isn't there a more nice one than using a temp .web file or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` is intended for loading the configuration for an executable and so really expects the full path to an .exe file. The config file is expected to be in the same directory as the .exe and have the extension .exe.config, so it isn't really suitable for loading the configuration of an ASP.NET website. A better choice is to use the `WebConfigurationManager`. The `OpenWebConfiguration` method is okay if you're opening the config from within the site since it expects the virtual path to the config, but if you're opening it from something like a console app then you'll need to look at the `OpenMappedWebConfiguration` method. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151451.aspx) gives an example how you might achieve this.

There's also a [previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513410/open-web-config-from-console-application) on Stack Overflow showing how to do this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, i knew this issue. But isn't there a way to do the same thing with OpenExeConfiguration?

Comment: @Harry `OpenExeConfiguration` is geared to opening the configuration of, well, .exe files, so not really. :) Check the Stack Overflow link i've added which gives a straight-forward way to use the `WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedConfiguration` method to open the config of an ASP.NET website from, say, a console app.

Comment: Read the post again, let myself use the small thing between my ears and must say... THANKs. This solution works and the link provided helped a lot. Thank you to all the others also, yours Harry

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the virtual path to a physical path first.

```
string configPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/server/folders/web.local");      
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configPath);
```

The ~ at the start of the virtual path goes to the root of your application.  If you are referencing a relative file from your page, you may not want to use it.

Comment: I'm not in a Webapplication or a Website, with this mehtod I'm not even quite sure if the programm is running on the same physical machine. Only thing i know, it will be the same network, and the user running the programm will be allowed to access the path :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the share exists it sounds like it could be a permissions issue. Have you tried giving *share* and *folder* permissions to the account the application is running under?

[image]

Comment: no it isn't an permission issue, folders and files are accessible.

Comment: Accessible to who? If you can't access the config file at that location, how are the files and folders accessible?