# Issue reading AppSetting key from another project's web.config

Tags: c#

I am facing weird issue in reading `appSetting` from `Web.Config`
I always get `null`.

Why so?

**Web.config**

```
<!-- Message setting-->
<add key="applicationType" value="release"/>
```

**Code:**

```
string applicationType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationType"];
```

**worth to mention here**

Web.config is part of another project and i am trying to access it from another project,

Comment: please post more of your web.config

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785541/accessing-another-projects-app-config-properties

Comment: Are you sure you have put this in the correct web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **worth to mention here**
>
> Web.config is part of another project and i am trying to access it
>   from another project,

That's your issue.

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` uses the configuration file tied to your entry assembly, you can't use one from a different project.

In this particular instance, your web.config should be a part of your project, in the root of the application

Comment: thanks everybody for correcting me. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Web.config` must be a part of project has been started.

[image]

If you have started `BotServiceHost`, the `ConfigurationManager` will be using `config` inside `BotServiceHost`. But for example if you started from console app(sandbox) same `dll`(`BotServiceHost`), you must add another `config` file inside this sandbox!

It's doesn't matter what are you using `app.config` or `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

If Your application contains multiple Visual Studio Projects, you need to make sure you are accessing key with same project and not from another project in your solution.

If you key belongs to another project in your solution then Here's the code to do the same.

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(file); //Path to your config file
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
string applicationType = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["applicationType"].Value;
```

Please follow below link for more information. 
[ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is possible, you just need to open the file, for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for correcting me. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This isn't really suitable for web.config - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8097769/131809