# Is it possible to load web-config from console application?

Tags: c#, web-applications, configuration, console-application

My question is quite simple. I have a third party library which assumes that it will is used in a web site (needs special configuration sections in web.config). I would like to use this library in a C# console application. It is possible?

I have tried 
    `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration();`
as well as just copy everything into app.config but it does not work. The error I receive is a ConfigurationErrorsException stating that 

`An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for ...: Could not load type 'Configuration.RenderingSection' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Answer (score 4):

You can set [APP_CONFIG_FILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(string name, Object data)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string webconfigPath = "whatever......../web.config");
string webconfigDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(configPath);

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APPBASE", webconfigDir);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", webconfigPath);
```

It is easy and you will get same setting for console application (cron) and web application.

Comment: Plain and simple. Might I suggest you change the example you provide to use an actual pseudo path for the web.config instead of "whatever......./web.config". only for clarity

Comment: @Loligans I don't know the actual path. I suppose that it depends on relative the location of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.config` instead.

Exactly the same syntax, options, etc. as web.config, but for console and WinForms applications.

Also, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513410/open-web-config-from-console-application), i haven't tested it though but it seems to work for the guy. But, still i would suggest to use app.config if your project has nothing to do with web.

Comment: It's not a good idea having lots of .config files for the very same settings. When there are console applications deployed along with a website it's wise to centralize all the settings in a single file. Just consider the case of a web system that relies on console applications to launch periodic batch processes.

Comment: @YvánEcarri do you know how to share config-files between applications like you have said? This is the exact setup I have but I can't get it to work...