# Referencing another config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two projects in one solution.
Project A: MVC web app , (web.config)
Project B: console app, (app.config)
I want to access the web.config file of the main Mvc project because the console app is going to do some data transfer that req some settings in the web.config file. I wanted to reference the web.cong file in the app.config so if we config change I will not have to copy new code into app.confg

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Why can't you just create the settings in the app.config file? Is there a reason the two applications need to be aware of one another? (I'd personally keep them separate unless you've got a REALLY compelling reason not to)

Comment: The MVC project has data like: connection string, membership and role manager info, and possibly some other information that I think should be referenced vs. copied from the MVC project so if for example connection string changes before release, I don't have to copy code, also if they forget to tell me that they made the changes I wouldn't have to worry because it would look to referenced config file

Answer (score 0):

I think [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513410/open-web-config-from-console-application) has [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/516455/942416) you're looking for.

I quote the relevant parts of that answer here for completeness:

```
VirtualDirectoryMapping vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(@"C:\test", true);
WebConfigurationFileMap wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);

// Get the Web application configuration object.
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
```

> This is assuming you have a file called web.config in a directory called C:\Test.
>
> You must also reference System.Web and System.configuration and any dlls containing configuration handlers that are set up in your web.config.